# How to stop ongoing process node server when user close the tab?

Tags: javascript, node.js, abortcontroller

Lets suppose user have requested to download transaction csv and it take around 10 minutes. If user close the tab and go away , will the process continue on server . If yes, how should we handle such scenario ?

Can i use AbortSignal class to stop the on going process in node.js server if user close the tab or browser ?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal/abort_static
Is this going to work, to handle this current situation

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.